# Transform cookie expiry value in readable format

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, behat

I would ask you guys, 
I am writing test for checking expiry date for a chosen site.
If is possible that someone help me in solving following:
Have value

> expiry

from cookie and is:

```
1561291056
```

Can someone help me - if there is any way to convert it to some more human readable value. 
Or viceversa option, I can see expiry date from

`DevTools->Application->Cookies`

how can convert it to above presented value (1561291056).
I know I can not pickup simply from

`Cookies->tab Expiry`

Searched but without any success.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's date() function.

Example:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', 1561291056);
```

It should return

> 06/23/2019

Comment: Wow, what a simple solution, Thank you @Dylan Kas